# How to assign a JSON value to a var in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to assign a JSON value to var, however i get the following error.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/memah.jpg)

```
var a = { myData.results[count].category[count] }
```

Comment: Don't screenshot error messages. Copy/transcribe the text.

Comment: Cause you dont have a key? Key values stores (objects) need a *key* and a *value*

Comment: Or just drop the curlies, if it is not supposed to be a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a syntax error, either make it a property of an object:

```
var a = { prop: myData.results[count].category[count] };
```

Or just the value:

```
var a = myData.results[count].category[count];
```